# Filtering out duplicates from database but preserving the originals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get list of ids of duplicate rows in my table so I can delete them using `where id in`.
Here is my table :

```
id|col1|col2
1 |22  | text
2 |22  | text
3 |23  | text
4 |22  | text2
```

So in here ids `1` and `2` are duplicates other are not. So I know how to get them by using `group by and having count(*) > 1`

But I want to keep one and delete the others. So this is how this table would look like after purge of duplicates :

```
    id|col1|col2
    1 |22  | text
    3 |23  | text
    4 |22  | text2
```

or :

```
id|col1|col2
2 |22  | text
3 |23  | text
4 |22  | text2
```

Either one is fine. How can I do this? Get rid of the duplicates but keep one of the duplicates at the end making it not a duplicate anymore?

My next goal is to add indexes to these fields so this won't happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
delete from table_name
where id not in (select min(id)
                 from table_name
                 group by col1, col2);
```

It will delete all rows with non minimal `id` in every `col1, col2` group.

Alternative query:

```
delete from table_name t1
where exists (select *
              from table_name t2
              where t1.col1 = t2.col2
                and t1.col2 = t2.col2
                and t1.id < t2.id );
```

It does the same thing, just in other way.

Answer (score 0):

Igor Romanchenko gave good solutions, another one could be:

```
with cte as c (
    select id, row_number() over(partition by col1, col2 order by id) as rn
    from Table1
)
delete Table1 as t
from cte as c
where c.id = t.id and c.rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one may be a little slower

```
DELETE FROM tab
NATURAL JOIN 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT ON(col2, col3) id AS target, col2, col3
   FROM tab
   ORDER by col2, col3 /* can add order by id if you care which is kept */
) AS subq WHERE tab.id <> subq.target;
```

but I'd try it on sample data to see.